# Фильтр по вложенности списков

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список с такими данными:

```
['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111]
['qwerty']
['PostCode', '!=', 'qwerty']
['PersonId']
['ID']
```

как его отфильтровать, чтобы получить:

```
['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111]
['PostCode', '!=', 'qwerty']
```

Comment: А где здесь кортежи? Я вижу 5 отдельных списков, причём только один из них присваивается в переменную. Так то фильтровать можете по длине списка.

Comment: Спасибо! Уже нашёл! Как раз читаю статью  про длину списка! Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ну вы в любом случае вложите эти списки в ещё один список. Сейчас это у вас один список, присваиваемый в переменную `test` и ещё 4 списка, просто так висящие в пространстве. Если этот код попытаться выполнить, то будет ошибка отступа.

Comment: CrazyElf Да конечно, я с помощью вашего наставления, и с помощью len получил необходимый результат: filter_1 = [t for t in test if len(test) == 3]   но вот теперь проблема в том что результат выводит пустые списки [] , теперь воюю с этим...(( ПС изначально не правильно поставил вопрос! у меня уже переменная содержит в  себе все списки из tkinter-a = эти самые списки, это строки

Comment: `if len(t) == 3` вообще-то, а не `len(test) == 3` )

Comment: CrazyElf в том то и дело что нет! по идее должен работать именно ваш код с вашим замечанием но он выводит ошибку: TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: CrazyElf Я сейчас создам вопрос, думал проблема с тем что в переменной несколько списков но нет.....

Comment: В чём проблема я вам уже несколько раз написал, начиная с самого первого комментария. Переменная `test` должна быть списком списков, а у вас это похоже один список, а остальные списки вы просто выкидываете так, как вы их написали в коде. Должно быть условно так: `test = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` Видите списки в списке? А у вас нет этого вложения.

Answer (score 1):

С использованием встроенной функции `filter`:

```py
lists = [
         ['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111],
         ['qwerty'],
         ['PostCode', '!=', 'qwerty'],
         ['PersonId'],
         ['ID']
]

def is_three_len(lst):
    return len(lst) == 3

results = filter(is_three_len, lists)
print(list(results))
```

Выводит:

```
[['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111], ['PostCode', '!=', 'qwerty']]
```