# Ошибка TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему код:

```
test = ['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111]
filter_1 = [t for t in test if len(t) == 3]
print(filter_1)
```

выводит ошибку:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: Так у вас в [исходном вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1517582/1365) подразумевается список списков, из которого нужно вытащить только списки длиной 3, а теперь вы пытаетесь из одного из этих подсписков вытащить списки (которых нет, потому что это одни плоский список)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт:

```
test = [['sum_for_pivot', '=', 1111]]
filter_1 = [t for t in test if len(t) == 3]
print(filter_1)
```